# SQL inserted value of a table as column of another table

Tags: sql

```
      Table1                     Table2

      Id Name               Id Table1Id Value
      1  Some                1   1      value1
      2  Some1               2   2      value2
      3  Some2               3   3      value3
      4  Some3
          .
          .
```

I want to result this:

```
     Some    Some1    Some2     Some3
     value1  value2   value3    NULL
```

When I entered value into the Table1 I want to look like the table2's column, how can I do this?

I guess I'm looking for pivot query.

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to insert into table1? At the moment it sounds like you want 1 row in table1 for each column in table2, but surely that isn't right?

Comment: Table2 only have one column Id

Comment: so if you add a row (4, Some3) to Table1, you would need to alter table2 to have another column? What DB are you doing this for, and what is its upper limit on columns for a table (and hence on rows in Table1)?

Comment: i dont want to alter table, i just look like with some select query

Comment: What @mc110 is saying is that we don't understand your question. It looks like you want to run some query against the two tables and don't know how. OK, fine. But without telling us what you want the results of the query to look like, and how the two tables are related we can't help.

Comment: I think there is a problem of concept, you can not use fields as rows, your problem should be solveable without making this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting the additional information.  Based on what you said, you're looking for a PIVOT statement that will turn each `name` in Table1 into a column header, containing the corresponding `value` from Table2.

Have a look at the following SQL, which produces the output your sample data indicates.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (ID INT, Name varchar(5))
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (ID INT, Table1ID INT, Value varchar(6))

INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID, Name) SELECT 1, 'Some'
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID, Name) SELECT 2, 'Some1'
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID, Name) SELECT 3, 'Some2'
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID, Name) SELECT 4, 'Some3'

INSERT INTO #Table2 (ID, Table1ID, Value) SELECT 1, 1, 'Value1'
INSERT INTO #Table2 (ID, Table1ID, Value) SELECT 2, 2, 'Value2'
INSERT INTO #Table2 (ID, Table1ID, Value) SELECT 3, 3, 'Value3'

-- List of values to be columns
declare @cols nvarchar(max) 
select @cols = coalesce(@cols+N',', N'') + quotename(Name) from #Table1 order by ID
PRINT @Cols

declare @query varchar(MAX)
SET @query = '
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT T1.Name, T2.Value
    FROM 
        #Table1 T1
         INNER JOIN 
        #Table2 T2 ON 
            T1.ID = T2.Table1ID
  ) s
PIVOT
  (
  MAX(Value) FOR Name IN ('+@Cols+')
  )  p'

PRINT @query
EXEC (@query)

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```